# Node's attributes from a different dataset

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I need to merge some info from different datasets to build a dataset that includes nodes, edges and nodes' attributes.

The first dataset (df1) is something like this:

```
Node     Edge
A         B
A         D
B         N
B         A
B         X
S         C
```

The second dataset includes unique nodes and their properties:

```
Node    Attribute
A           -1
B           0
C           -1.5
D           1
...
N           1
... 
X           0
Y           -1.5
W          -1.5
Z           1
```

I would like to create a graph using the links as in the first dataset (df1), coloring nodes based on the attribute values:

```
 - if -1.5 then grey    
 - if -1 then red
 - if 0 then orange
 - if 1 then yellow
 - if 1.5 then green
```

For building the graph I can use

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='Node', target='Edge')
```

Then I will need to set the above rules for assigning the color and add them as attribute of nodes.
My question is on how I can include these rules as node's attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is to get the attributes DataFrame into something more usable. We can create a mapping from Node to colour by [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to Node, and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the current attribute numerical value into a colour:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

edges_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Node': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'S'],
    'Edge': ['B', 'D', 'N', 'A', 'X', 'C']
})

# Abridged but contains values for all nodes in `edges_df`
attributes_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Node': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'N', 'S', 'X'],
    'Attribute': [-1, 0, -1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 0]
})

mapper = {-1.5: 'grey', -1: 'red', 0: 'orange', 1: 'yellow', 1.5: 'green'}
colour_map = attributes_df.set_index('Node')['Attribute'].map(mapper)
```

`colour_map`:

```
Node
A       red
B    orange
C      grey
D    yellow
N    yellow
S     green
X    orange
Name: Attribute, dtype: object
```

*Note: Neither the value `1.5` nor node `S` were represented in the above Attributers Dataset so to have all nodes with colour and to have all colours represented `S` was set to `1.5` in `attributes_df`

---

`colour_map` can then be used to either [`set_node_attributes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html):

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges_df, source='Node', target='Edge')
# Add Attribute to each node
nx.set_node_attributes(G, colour_map, name="colour")

# Then draw with colours based on attribute values:
nx.draw(G, 
        node_color=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'colour').values(),
        with_labels=True)
```

Or we can use the Series directly (without creating node attributes) by [`reindexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) based on the Graph nodes to ensure colours appear in the same order as they do in `G.nodes()` this makes sure the correct colours align with the correct nodes:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges_df, source='Node', target='Edge')

# Then draw with colours based on the Series:
nx.draw(G, 
        node_color=colour_map.reindex(G.nodes()),
        with_labels=True)
```

Either approach we get a graph like:

[image: coloured and labeled plot]